# Add overlay text on a html5 video using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

For this html:

```
<html>
<div id="vids">
   <video id="vid-1" src="vid1.mp4">
   </video>
   <video id="vid-2" src="vid2.mp4">
   </video>
</div>
</html>
```

The videos show up correctly.
I want to add an overlay text (caption) on top of each video like: 
"Video 1 - Greenery"
"Video 2 - Island"

How can I do this using Javascript alone *without modifying the HTML*?
If not overlay, how do I display caption right above or below each video.

I have tried this:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("vid-1");
vid.insertAdjacentHTML("aftereend","Video 1 - Greenery");
```

But the text "Video 1 - Greenery", appears on right side of video.
If it appeared directly above or below video that would work too.

Comment: What do you mean "without modifying the HTML"? You _are_ modifying the HTML right now. Just add some CSS that's the same dimensions as the video, then set its position to absolute.

Comment: The HTML is dynamically generated by another program. There can be any number of video elements generated under the div (here i have shown only two). Using javascript, i am trying to overlay the videos with captions.

Comment: @Jasper2000 You have no control over and can therefore not modify the (incoming) HTML _source_, but modifying the "live HTML" (the DOM) via JS is allowed? Do I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

- Prefer to use [`<figcaption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) (and [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)).
- "Placing above" is solved with CSS; see e.g. [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute).

---

We can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) video IDs to captions. Then for all entries, we can create and [insert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) the captions before their corresponding videos:

```js
const idToCaption = new Map();
idToCaption.set("vid-1", "Video 1 - Greenery");
idToCaption.set("vid-2", "Video 2 - Island");

for (const [id, caption] of idToCaption.entries()) {
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = caption;
  
  const video = document.getElementById(id);
  
  // Assign caption as label
  p.id = `${id}-label`;
  video.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", p.id);
  
  video.parentElement.insertBefore(p, video);
}
```

```html
<div id="vids">
  <video id="vid-1" src="vid1.mp4"></video>
  <video id="vid-2" src="vid2.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

**Note**:

- To place the captions after their videos, [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore#referencenode) the video's [next sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).
- For accessibility reasons we should declare the captions to label the videos, e.g. via [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby). (Captions labelling content is done implicitly when using `<figcaption>` as below.)

Without styling, the captions will come before their videos. To place them *above* their videos we need styling (CSS).

Placing elements above others can be achieved by taking them out of the flow, e.g. with [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute).

We want to position the captions relative to the videos. But the captions are siblings and not children of the videos, which makes relative positioning more difficult.

We can **wrap each caption and its video** in another element, which will effectively represent the video. That way, the caption is a child of the "video" (the wrapper), which makes positioning it correctly easier:

```js
const idToCaption = new Map();
idToCaption.set("vid-1", "Video 1 - Greenery");
idToCaption.set("vid-2", "Video 2 - Island");

for (const [id, caption] of idToCaption.entries()) {
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = caption;
  
  const video = document.getElementById(id);
  
  p.id = `${id}-label`;
  video.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", p.id);
  
  // New code starts here
  const wrapper = document.createElement("span");
  wrapper.classList.add("wrapper");
  
  p.classList.add("caption");
  
  video.replaceWith(wrapper);
  wrapper.append(p, video);
}
```

```css
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  /*Example: Position at top-left*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  /* `position:absolute` elements are relative to
   * first non-`static` ancestor.
   * Make wrapper non-`static`. */
  position: relative;
  
  /* `display:inline-block` makes
   * `.wrapper` behave like <video>,
   * but contain it (here: inherit its size). */
  display: inline-block;
}

/*Ignore; presentational*/
.caption {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
video {border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<div id="vids">
  <video id="vid-1" src="vid1.mp4"></video>
  <video id="vid-2" src="vid2.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

There already exist elements for captions and the wrapper: [`<figcaption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) and [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure). You should **prefer these** where applicable, e.g. here:

```js
const idToCaption = new Map();
idToCaption.set("vid-1", "Video 1 - Greenery");
idToCaption.set("vid-2", "Video 2 - Island");

for (const [id, caption] of idToCaption.entries()) {
  const figcaption = document.createElement("figcaption");
  figcaption.textContent = caption;
  
  const video = document.getElementById(id);
  
  /* Notice that <figcaption> automatically applies to its
   * <figure>'s other content. No "aria-labelledby" required anymore! */
  
  const figure = document.createElement("figure");
  
  video.replaceWith(figure);
  figure.append(figcaption, video);
}
```

```css
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

figure {position: relative}

/*Ignore; presentational*/
figcaption {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
video {border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<div id="vids">
  <video id="vid-1" src="vid1.mp4"></video>
  <video id="vid-2" src="vid2.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

**Note**: The `<figure>` element is `display: block` whereas `<video>` is `display: inline` by default. The stylesheet should fix this inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

```
var customStyle="z-index: 2;    background: red;    position: absolute;    top: 50%;    right: 50%;";
    var vid = document.querySelector("video");
    vid.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",`<p style="${customStyle}">Video 1 - Greenery</p>`);
```

Style is just for example purposes.

Naturallly better is to use file styles.

insertAdjacentHTML renders an Element, so if You put a raw text, then it creates a textNode.

Better to wrap it in some tag - then style has access to it.

using `${customStyle}` You make it easier to maintain.

It's easier to set dynamic elements with it's inline styes than to operate on window stylesheets.
This solution makes styling Your text possible.

Comment: How does this solve the issue? Why are you using inline styles? What is `background: ed`? Please explain in more detail.